# How to compare a uk date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have to do a check that a date stored in a database in UK date format dd/mm/yyyy is greater than a given date, e.g 01/01/2010 - what is the best way to go about this? Thanks

Comment: Is the date in the database stored in UK format, or is the the date that you wish to compare it against that is in UK format? If you are using a [DATETIME, DATE, or TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) column, then it will be stored in a standard date format.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have your dates stored as a string. In that case you may want to use the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   your_table
WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(your_field, '%d/%m/%Y') > '2010-01-01';
```

As [@OMG Ponies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135152/omg-ponies) noted in a comment below, you won't be able to use an index on your column for such a query. Therefore, it would probably be a better idea to convert your dates to use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` data types:

```
-- Add a new DATETIME column
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN your_new_field DATE;

-- Fill in your new column
UPDATE your_table SET your_new_field = STR_TO_DATE(your_field, '%d/%m/%Y');

-- Drop your old string column
ALTER TABLE your_table DROP COLUMN your_field;

-- Rename your new column to the previous name
ALTER TABLE your_table CHANGE your_new_field your_field DATE;
```

Then date comparisons will also be much easier:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   your_table
WHERE  your_field > '2010-01-01';
```

If you want to display your date using the UK format, you can simply use the [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function as follows:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(your_field, '%d/%m/%Y')
FROM   your_table
WHERE  your_field > '2010-01-01';
```

And finally, if you want to compare your date field with a date string formatting as a UK date, you can use the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function again:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(your_field, '%d/%m/%Y')
FROM   your_table
WHERE  your_field > STR_TO_DATE('2010-01-01', '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Comment: Won't be able to use an index if one exists on the date column with this answer.